# How to quickly set up Git for teams using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

I still can't really figure out if I should go with Mercurial or Git. Git is directly supported by Xcode, and Mercurial isn't. So it might be clever to stay with Apple and use what they prefer.

Since Git and Mercurial are pretty much the same thing though, I see no big reason why to use Mercurial anyways.

But now the problem is: How to set up Git so that 5 devs can work on the same project, everyone having a full working copy locally on their machine, and then pushing their results back to an central repo where everyone else can pull the final super-merge back in?

I guess there is a good tutorial somewhere? The other devs in the team don't want to mess around in the command line since coding is hard enough. Are there any GUIs for Git that make creating and maintaining the repository an easy thing?

Snow Leopard, btw... I've found this Git Installer for Mac OS X, but it doesn't mention if this runs on Snow Leopard. Not sure if this is the original good thing:

http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount

**Edit: Confusing! Someone told me Xcode has Git integration, but it only has SVN!** OK so even if I still stick with Git, how can I get started with a GUI at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 will have git support built-in.

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#version-editor