# GitX GUI with Git: How to set up the repository for an Xcode project?

Tags: git, gitx

GitX seems to need an already-set-up repository, so although it seems to be the best GUI for Git, it is incomplete. I still need to create the project repository manually in the console.

Whats the fastest way to get started with GitX? The website of GitX assumes that I'm already a Git nerd. I'm not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to quickly set up Git for teams using Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250429/how-to-quickly-set-up-git-for-teams-using-xcode)

Comment: This question reduces to your previous one, since setting up the repository doesn't have anything to do with gitx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitX is not a complete command-line replacement. It doesn't create repositories or push/pull/fetch remotes, among other things. Use git to do those bits, and GitX for what it does best: browsing history and committing, among other things.

Also of note: Use the `GitX -> Enable Terminal Usage` menu so you can type `gitx` from the command line within a git repository.

I don't know what the *best* way to get started is. I just cracked it open and started pushing buttons and pulling levers.