# How to set up a Git repository for an Xcode project?

Tags: git, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to quickly set up Git for teams using Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250429/how-to-quickly-set-up-git-for-teams-using-xcode)

I have an Xcode project folder on my Mac HD. Snow Leopard. The GitX GUI expects that I already have an Git repository. So I guess since I have GitX installed, I also have Git, and now I need to be cool and intelligent and know what to hack into the Terminal. But what? Is there any tutorial that explains this in minutes, not hours or even days?

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250429/how-to-quickly-set-up-git-for-teams-using-xcode

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. Edit your previous question if it doesn't accurately reflect what you need to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just `git init` in that folder

[this](http://linux.csc.ncsu.edu/wiki/Git%20in%2020%20minutes) is a 20 minute git link

and [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/everyday.html) is a every day most needed commands

and [this](http://book.git-scm.com/) is the community book for further reading

this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) will help you also

Answer (score 3):

See this:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#creating-a-new-repository

Basically, go into the root of your project and type:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit
```

(And note the `.` ad the end of the `git add .` command.)